# Precedence constraint does not run in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio

Hope you are doing well.
I have a Precedence constraint that does not work . Putting it into more clear way ,  the package is executed successfully up until the components in which I have the precedence constraint as you can see here:

[image]

I call a procedure in the component before the "precedence and constraint" component and when I execute the procedure in SSMS it gives me the correct result . But I have no  idea why it does not work in here.
Here are some other pictures related to this issue:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: nobody here has the knowledge of using SSIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the stored procedure from the Execute SQL Task add the `OUTPUT` keyword to the parameter that will be returned.  For instance

```
EXEC dbo.OpenExcel ?, ?, ? OUTPUT
```